# Does docker container work differently in terms of running inside a host from VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-vpc

I have configured a private VPC in AWS Aurora cluster. There are a couple of SQL scripts that need to run from `codebuild project` to configure the database in the Aurora cluster. These scripts are running inside a docker container. And I am using IAM authentication. The problem I have is I always got `FATAL: password authentication failed for user` error in the codebuild project. The password is auto-generated via `aws rds generate-db-auth-token`.

There is no issue if I use Aurora master username and password. That means the connectivity of VPC between codebuild and Aurora should work.

I have tested that it works fine if I remove VPC and put everything in the public network. That means the codebuild role is configured correctly.

Based on that, I assume the issue happens when I use IAM authentication with VPC from the docker container. I wonder whether there is any special configuration for that?

Comment: So does `aws rds generate-db-auth-token` work? How did you enable access to RDS service from private subnet? Using NAT or RDS VPC endpoint?

Comment: `aws rds generate-db-auth-token` works but it runs directly from the codebuild step not from docker. I am not using NAT. us RDS VPC endpoint.